# Do product IDs for in-app-purchase have to be globally unique per Apple ID (not just local per app)?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I want to define a new product for in-app-purchase in iTunes Connect, however I get this error message:

> The product ID you entered has already been used. Enter a unique
>   product ID and try again.

Does this mean that product IDs have to be globally unique per Apple ID (I am already using the same product ID in another app)? So far I was under the impression that local uniqueness per app is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Apple's [In-App Purchase Configuration Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Appendices/InAppPurchaseProperties.html) ProductIDs have to be globally unique:

> ProductID: The globally unique UTF-8 alphanumerical identifier for the
>   product. The Product ID is any sequence of letters and numbers that
>   uniquely identify the product. It can include periods and underscores
>   and can be as long as 255 bytes, assuming single-byte characters. This
>   value is used in the app to identify the product. It can’t be used for
>   more than one product or the same product on Mac apps and iOS apps.

That's why you usually define them using reverse domain notation:

```
com.yourdomain.appname.productId
```

You can use the productId part of this ID in boths apps doing something like this:

```
com.yourdomain.appname1.productId
com.yourdomain.appname2.productId
```

Comment: Thx. Any reason either lower case (`com.yourdomain.appname1.productid`) or camel case (`com.yourdomain.AppName1.ProductId`) for the parts defined in iTunes Connect might be better?

Comment: No reason for lower case. Camel case is fine, too.

Comment: Where is stated that ProductIds have to be globally unique?
Seems to me that Apple suggests it but does not require it.

Comment: @CesarVarela thanks for your comment. I found it in Apple's In-App Purchase Configuration Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Appendices/InAppPurchaseProperties.html (I added the quote to the answer)

Comment: That documentation says "A unique ID you give to your in-app purchase to identify the product. The product ID can contain letters, numbers, hyphens, periods, and underscores can be as long as 255 characters. You need separate identifiers for in-app purchases in your macOS app and your iOS app." Doesn't say "globally unique".

Comment: Based on my tests, productIDs don't have to be globally unique.

Comment: Seems it just needs to be unique across your own apps